# How are buckets isolated on Forge autodesk?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

Description of observations:

- Between several apps I own, if I create a bucket in one, I am not allowed in the other. I assume I could but no (exemple, an app for dev/staged/prod with same bucket name), I have *"reason": "Bucket already exists"*.
- When I create a new app and try to create some buckets, with some common names (azerty/qwerty/demo/test/...), it is not possible, because it tells me *"reason": "Bucket already exists"* This makes me wonder if another app can grab some buckets name I then cannot use. (note: when I use random names like uuid or like, I never have conflict)

How are buckets isolated on Forge autodesk?
How should I consider to use bucket name?
(since current observation makes me think buckets are not so isolated between apps...)

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are correct on the understanding on bucket name. From the API help, the requirement is

> A unique name you assign to a bucket. It must be globally unique across 
>   all applications and regions, otherwise the call will fail. Possible 
>   values: -_.a-z0-9 (between 3-128 characters in length). Note that you 
>   cannot change a bucket key.

i.e. it is global unique. Currently, I do not see a way to check if it is unique before creating a new bucket, while normally if such format would be working: < your company name >.< your app name >.< your bucket name in this app >, While since Forge has not something like Java group id registration, such name might probably be also conflict if other customer happened to create by such name, but much lower possibility.

another of my practice is: < your app client id >.< your bucket name in this app >. Since client id is unique, this will ensure the final bucket name is unique. It would also be helpful to find which app this bucket belongs to.

generic guid is fine, while you would have to manage a map on what the bucket is for.